# How to have multiple upper bounds for the generic type parameter of a function?

Tags: kotlin, generics

There are an abstract class `Base` and a interface `BaseAction`. In my project, `A` and  `B` both implements `Base`, `BaseAction`.

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract fun doAction()
}

interface BaseAction {

}

class A: Base(), BaseAction {
    override fun doAction() {

    }
}

class B: Base(), BaseAction {
    override fun doAction() {

    }
}
```

Now I define an abstract class `AbstractCommand` and there is a function:

```
abstract class AbstractCommand {
    abstract fun <T> getActions(): List<T> where T: Base, T: BaseAction

    fun doSomething() {
        // Here A and B both are Ok for me.
        getActions<>()
    }

}
```

As you see, there are two upper bounds: `Base` and `BaseAction`. In function `doSomething`, I want to invoke `getActions`，in that List，class A and B both are ok for me.

**My question is how I can invoke `getActions`.**

## EDIT

Yes I can define T in class `AbstractCommand`, but if so, AbstractCommand only return List<`A`> or List<`B`>. However List is expected.

## EDIT

It's my fault for my description. I must explain more about my question and explain it's not suitable to let A and B extends same parent directly.

In fact, my question is more complex as describe above. Let me hold my full example.

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract fun doAction()
}

interface BuyGiftAction {
    abstract fun buyGift()
}

abstract class A: Base(){
    abstract fun doActionA()
}

abstract class B: Base() {
    abstract fun doActionB()
}
```

As you see, A and B both extends Base class and define new abstract function. Now child of A want to implement `BuyGiftAction` and child of B does so.

```
class ChildA: A(), BuyGiftAction {
    override fun doActionA() {
    }

    override fun doAction() {
    }

    override fun buyGift() {
    }
}

class ChildB: B(), BuyGiftAction {
    override fun doActionB() {
    }

    override fun doAction() {
    }

    override fun buyGift() {
    }
}
```

Obviously it's very not suitable to let `A` and `B` both extend a class named `Parent` who extends `Base` and implements `BuyGiftAction`.

```
abstract class AbstractCommand {
    abstract fun <T> getActionArray(): Array<T> where T: Base, T: BuyGiftAction

    fun doSomething() {
        // Here ChildA and ChildB both are Ok for me.
        getActionArray<>()
    }

}
```

[Try it here!](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: List is not a valid type the generic type parameter is missing. Do you mean `List<Any>`?

Comment: @WilliMentzel Item in list should extends Base and implements BaseAction.

Comment: But It can always only be List<A> or List<B>, those are the only types that extend Base and implements BaseAction.

Comment: @WilliMentzel So I am confused and want to know if there an other way to implement this.

Comment: @WilliMentzel OP wants a heterogeneous list of both As and Bs, which I'm not sure we can have unless we specify a single common parent type.

Comment: @CoXavier But I see what you mean... you want to call getActions<A> and doSomething shoould call getActions with A as parameter as well. That is not possible. Where would that generic type "persisted" so that doSomething "knows" it?

Comment: @Joffrey I am not sure about that. I guess he wants what I described above, but maybe I am confused :D

Comment: @CoXier let's pretend AbstractCommand compiles as layed out by you, can you please show a call-site example?

Comment: Yep, I'd also like to get examples of how you want to use this. Also, it's unclear why you need abstract classes anywhere here as opposed to interfaces, and it's unclear why making `BuyGiftAction` extend the Base interface would be a problem in that case

Comment: @WilliMentzel Code link is updated.

Comment: @Joffrey It's a long story. But above code is meaningful right?

Comment: @CoXier the link still doesn't show how you want to *use* `AbstractCommand`

Comment: @CoXier *above code is meaningful right?* - not really. I can't see in this code in which case you would want an instance of `BuyGiftAction` that is not also an instance of `Base`. Acknowledging that `BuyGiftAction` is always a `Base` would just solve your problem here (either make them both abstract classes or both interfaces).

Comment: @Joffrey I update code in the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224623/discussion-between-coxier-and-joffrey).

Answer (score 0):

In order for `doSomething` to use the same `T` as `getActions`, you need to make `T` a generic type parameter of `AbstractCommand`:

```
abstract class AbstractCommand<T> where T: Base, T: BaseAction {
    abstract fun getActions(): List<T>

    fun doSomething() {
        getActions()
    }
}
```

Comment: However I don't want AbstractCommand only map A or B。A and B both should be ok.

Comment: As you see, in the future, C 、D、E  are coming. But A B C D E both extends Base and implements BaseAction.

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined `getActions()` currently means you return a list of a *single* type `T` which needs to both extend `Base` and implement `BaseAction`. So either only `A`s in your list, or only `B`s, but you cannot mix `A`s and `B`s here.

If you want heterogeneous types in your list, you will have to make `getActions()` return something else than `T`, something like a single base class.

I think the easiest way would be to make the base class `Base` implement `BaseAction`, or to create an intermediate class (e.g. `Action`) that both extends `Base` and implement `BaseAction`, and which `A` and `B` could derive from.

```kotlin
abstract class Action : Base(), BaseAction

class A: Action() {
    override fun doAction() { ... }
}

class B: Action() {
    override fun doAction() { ... }
}
abstract class AbstractCommand {
    abstract fun getActions(): List<Action>

    fun doSomething() {
        // Here A and B both are Ok for me.
        getActions()
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it is not about the list being able to hold A and B at the same time, I guess what he wants is that getActions in doSomething uses the same T he called getActions originally with. If he calls getActions again with another type for T, doSomething's getActions() should use that then. That is not possible. But OP should correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @WilliMentzel If this is really what OP needs then he should be happy with your answer. Let's wait for OP's comment to clarify. But the need for heterogenous list is what I understood from the EDIT part of the question, and from his comments on your answer.